Flutter devtools Deep Links not working: your flutter project has no Links to verify
I recently migrated my project to Flutter 3.22, I am trying to access new feature "Deep Links" in the dev tools, but it says "Your Flutter project has no Links to verify"
I am using deep link in my flutter project and it is working properly.
AndroidManifect file
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data
        android:scheme="https" 
        android:host="www.example.com"
        android:pathPrefix="/user"
        />                
</intent-filter>


What am I doing wrong, please help me.
I have checked my manifest file and /.well-known/assetlinks.json file

Did you find the issue?
